# SQL: How do i convert period per column to period per row

Tags: sql, odbc

I am using a Microsoft ODBC Data source to pull data from an excel spreadsheet so I cannot use the pivot / unpivot functions to help transpose data. Also the format of the spreadsheet is fixed so it cannot be changed within excel :(

I need to change the format of the following example table:
[image: Original Data]

To this format:

[image: Required Format]

There can be N number of projects and N number of components.
Generally the number periods will always be the same but there could be up to 40 of them. But I would love to see a dynamic solutions if possible for N periods.

Also an alternative format would be to have a column per component:
[image: column per component]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a staging table that matches the format of your input file.  Just truncate it, then import your excel spreadsheet into it.  Once the data is there, you can use pivot tables as needed.  As an aside, avoid using dynamic SQL if possible.

If you don't want to go that route, you would have to write specific SQL for just this case.

Example:

```
SELECT [Project Name], '2015' AS [Period], [2015] AS [Value]
FROM your spreadsheet

UNION ALL

SELECT [Project Name], '2016' AS [Period], [2016] AS [Value]
From your spreadsheet

Order By Project Name, Period
```

Comment: The period derivation should be a string.

Comment: @Rabbit Sorry, but I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: You are deriving [Period] using the column [2015]. So it's getting the value of the field named [2015] and putting it in a new column that you're calling [Period]. Basically [Period] = [Value] in your SQL. It should be `'2015' AS [Period]`

Comment: @Rabbit Oh My God - I actually had that correct the first time and for some reason edited it while I was doing something else.  You're right - thanks!

Comment: Thanks guys That worked a treat, The final example query as Rabbit pointed out would be:      SELECT [Project Name], '2015' AS [Period], [2015] AS [Value]
FROM your spreadsheet

UNION ALL

SELECT [Project Name], '2016' AS [Period], [2016] AS [Value]
From your spreadsheet

Order By Project Name, Period

Comment: @TimmyFuller Please remember to upvote any answers that helped you - and accept the answer that helps you the most.  This will help future users with similar questions more quickly find the best answer.

Comment: Sorry I forgot. I have done it now. Thanks again for your help.